# Tangent line $l$ through $(a,a^2)$ on $y=x^2 $, to make the area $S$ enclosed by $l$ and $y=-x^2+4x-1$ smallest. Find $l$ and $S$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Draw a tangent line $l$ through $(a,a^2)$ on $y=x^2 $, to make the area $S$ enclosed by $l$ and $y=-x^2+4x-1$ smallest. Find $l$ and $S$.

I was doing this:
$l$ : $y-a^2=2a(x-a)\Rightarrow y=2ax-a^2$
Supose $l$ intersect  $y=-x^2+4x-1$ at $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. Then 
$$S=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\Big(-x^2+4x-1-(2ax-a^2)\Big) dx$$
But $x_{1,2}$ is too complex make $S$ more complex. So I don't how to simply it also I was wondering is there more convenient way to do this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solution to $$x^2+x(2a-4)+1-a^2 =0$$ we have (by Vieta)
$$ x_1+x_2 = 4-2a\;\;\;\; {\rm and}\;\;\;\;\;x_1x_2 = 1-a^2\;\;\;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\;\;\;x_2-x_1=2\sqrt{2a^2-4a+3}$$
So

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
S(a)&=&\Big|\int_{x_1}^{x_2}(x^2+x(2a-4)+1-a^2) dx\Big|\\
 &=& \Big|{x^3\over 3}+x^2(a-2)+(1-a^2)x\Big{|}_{x_1}^{x_2}\;\;\Big|\\
 &=& \Big|(x_2-x_1)\Big({x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2\over 3}+(x_2+x_1)(a-2)+(1-a^2) \Big)\Big|\\
&=& \Big|2\sqrt{2a^2-4a+3}\cdot {-4a^2+8a-6\over 3}\Big| \\
&=& 4\sqrt{2a^2-4a+3}\cdot {2a^2-4a+3\over 3}\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Put $t = \sqrt{2a^2-4a+3}\geq 1$ for all $a$.  So $$S = {4\over 3}t^3\geq {4\over 3}$$ 
So $S_{\min} = 4/3$

Comment: Yep. I find it interesting that the minimizing tangent line parallels the line through the parabola’s intersection points. Coincidence?

Comment: BTW, +1 for not solving for $x_1$ and $x_2$ explicitly.

Comment: +1 especially for seeing the common terms ($2a^2-4a+3$) at the end and avoiding taking derivative. Please, fix $x_2-x_1$ in the 4th line.

Answer (score 1):

You solve the equation:
$$y=-x^2+4x-1=2ax-a^2=l \iff \\
x^2+2(a-2)x+1-a^2=0 \Rightarrow \\
x_1=2-a-\sqrt{2a^2-4a+3}; \ \ \ x_2=2-a+\sqrt{2a^2-4a+3}.$$
So:
$$\begin{align}x_1+x_2&=4-2a; \\
x_2-x_1&=2\sqrt{2a^2-4a+3};\\
x_1x_2&=1-a^2.\end{align}$$
The required area is:
$$S(a)=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}-x^2+4x-1-(2ax-a^2) dx=\\
\left(-\frac{x^3}{3}+(2-a)x^2+(a^2-1)x\right)\big{|}_{x_1}^{x_2}=\\
-\frac{x_2^3-x_1^3}{3}+(2-a)(x_2^2-x_1^2)+(a^2-1)(x_2-x_1)=\\
-\frac{(x_2-x_1)((x_2+x_1)^2-x_1x_2)}{3}+(2-a)(x_2-x_1)(x_2+x_1)+(a^2-1)(x_2-x_1)=\\
(x_2-x_1)\left[-\frac13((4-2a)^2-(1-a^2))+(2-a)(4-2a)+(a^2-1)\right]=\\
2\sqrt{2a^2-4a+3}\left[-\frac13(15-16a+5a^2)+8-8a+2a^2+a^2-1\right]=\\
2\sqrt{2a^2-4a+3}\left[\frac43a^2-\frac{8}{3}a+2\right].$$
To minimize this area function, you can set its derivative equal to zero:
$$S'(a)=\frac{4a-4}{\sqrt{2a^2-4a+3}}\left(\frac43a^2-\frac83a+2\right)+2\sqrt{2a^2-4a+3}\left(\frac83a-\frac83\right)=0 \Rightarrow \\
(4a-4)\left(\frac43a^2-\frac83a+2\right)+2(2a^2-4a+3)\left(\frac83a-\frac83\right)=0 \Rightarrow \\
(a-1)\left(\frac{16}{3}a^2-\frac{32}{3}a+8+\frac{32}{3}a^2-\frac{64}{3}a+16\right)=0 \Rightarrow \\
(a-1)(16a^2-32a+24)=0 \Rightarrow \\
8(a-1)(2a^2-4a+3)=0 \Rightarrow \\
a=1; \\
S(1)=\frac43.$$
Here is the graph (with $l=2x-1$):

$\hspace{2cm}$[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Your expression for the area is not equal to [greedoid’s](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2900431/265466). Which one is correct (if either)?

Comment: $x_1+x_2 = 4-2a$, not $4-a$. The expression for area should simplify nicely.

Comment: @amd, appreciate your comment, fixed it. I got interested in the solution when greedoid used $x_2-x_1=2\sqrt{3-4a}$ and wanted to double check and made the typo myself you spotted. I think now it is a complete (with all the derivatives and graphs), unanimous solution. Thanks again.

Comment: You can simplify the last part quite a bit: the area is a constant times a positive power of $2a^2-4a+3$, so you only need to minimize this expression.

Comment: yes, the problem is I had not recognized it was a positive power of that until I saw greedoid's solution. So I took a general approach (without knowing it).